# How to detect online and offline users php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to programming. Currently I'm working on a employee system using php and mysql. In that system I want to show the only online users in a table form. But sure how to separate which users in online and offline. Can anyone help my with this?

Comment: You can control it with the use of the flag `is_online`. Set it 1 when any user is login and mark it 0 when user is in-active or offline.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: I try to use the flag is_online but somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is back-end **PHP** and **MySQL** code, i am using [PHP Adodb library](https://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php). Now after logging into a site you can run this code to view online users

MY SQL CODE

```
CREATE TABLE `useronline` (
    `timestamp` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `ip` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `file` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`timestamp`),
    INDEX `ip` (`ip`),
    INDEX `file` (`file`)
)
```

PHP CODE

```
// expired time
$timeoutseconds = 600;

//get the time
$timestamp = time();
$timeout = $timestamp-$timeoutseconds;

// insert new user to table
$sql_checkip = "select * from $GLOBALS[db_sp].useronline where file = '".session_id()."'";
$rs_checkip = $GLOBALS["sp"]->getRow($sql_checkip);
if(!$rs_checkip['file']){
    $sql_in = " INSERT INTO $GLOBALS[db_sp].useronline SET
                timestamp ='$timestamp',
                ip = '" . getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')."',
                file = '" . session_id() ."'
                
            ";
    $GLOBALS["sp"]->execute($sql_in);
}

//delete values when they leave
$sql_del = "DELETE FROM useronline WHERE timestamp < $timeout";
$GLOBALS["sp"]->execute($sql_del);

//grab the results
$sql_useronlines = "SELECT DISTINCT file FROM $GLOBALS[db_sp].useronline";
$useronlines = count($GLOBALS["sp"]->getcol($sql));
return $useronlines;
```

Comment: where should I must add this php code? In a new php file or logincode.php? Sorry I'm confussed

Comment: It is best to add it at index.php. Every time the user reloads the page it will also execute

Comment: recommended code improvements: [inet6](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/inet6/) or a non-unicode for `ip` address. `file` as primary key matching the type of `session_id()`. `IODKU` for inserting/updating. Use prepared statements. `SELECT file... WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 600 SECONDS`. `DELETE` as out of band query.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume the table name is 'users' and give you a run down on how I would implement this.

First I would decide a time limit in which a user is considered to be active/online. Like 10 minutes?

I would then add 2 new fields to the database table:

- 'last_active' - timestamp
- 'last_logout' - timestamp

Every time a user logs in or requests a page  you should update last_active field with current time.

```
UPDATE users SET last_active = now()
WHERE id = ?
```

Everytime a user logs out update last_logout with current time.

```
UPDATE users SET last_logout = now()
WHERE id = ?
```

Then when you want to view a list of users who are online or active you would need to do a simple query that would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE last_active > last_logout 
AND last_active > (now() - interval 10 minute)
```

That will give you a list of users who have been active on the site in the last 10 mins and have not logged out.